# How to pass -L linker flag to rustc for cargo based project?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How do I make cargo pass `-L` linker flag to rustc invocations?

Comment: It seems you can't yet? https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/544

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is now possible using `.cargo/config`.

See https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1109 and http://doc.crates.io/config.html.

Answer (score 3):

Not yet. However, you can use a custom makefile for  given Cargo project instead.

For example, Servo uses the Skia library by having a Rust wrapper in the same cargo project, and a [`build`](https://github.com/servo/skia/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L7) key that calls a custom makefile.

You can do something similar in this case, for now.

Comment: In my case I was able to solve the problem using configure script that generates rs file with extern declaration and linker_args that then is used as module. configure is called by the cargo build key. I took rust/src/etc/mklldeps.py, changed it and called it by configure as I need dependency on LLVM libraries.

So basically the only reasonable way to change rustc invocation/call extern scripts is build key, you are right.