# How do you specify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH for a rust project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to experiment with rust.  In order to gain an understanding of how to invoke libraries created in other languages, I have created a tiny dynamic library in C whose .so file is in `../expclib1/libexp1.so`.

How do I inform intellij and rust that the implementation of

```
#[link(name="exp1")]
extern {
    fn bacon()->i32;
}
```

lives in `../expclib1/libexp1.so` ?  I know that in C you need to specify `-L../expclib1 -lexp1` in the link stage and then `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../expclib1` before trying to run it.  How do I make this work from cargo, and how do I make it work from intellij's run menu?  There are basically no options on the module inside of intellij, so I'm hoping that it can all be specified in the `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978808/how-to-pass-l-linker-flag-to-rustc-for-cargo-based-project) seems to be related to the cargo part.

Answer (score 3):

Extra link arguments for rust can be specified using the `build.rs` file which usually lives next to `Cargo.toml`.  Here is an example `build.rs`:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=../expclib1\n\
    cargo:rustc-link-search=/opt/oracle-jdk-bin-1.8.0.202/jre/lib/amd64/jli\n\
    cargo:rustc-link-search=/opt/oracle-jdk-bin-1.8.0.202/jre/lib/amd64/server\n\
    cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=exp1\n\
    cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=jli\n\
    cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=jvm");
}
```

That example should probably be a little smarter about finding the jni and jvm libraries, because not every system will be running java 1.8.0.202 installed in `/opt`.

The settings cargo uses from the output are documented in the [Build Scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) section of the rust documentation.

That only enables the application to link.  To enable it to run you must modify IntelliJ's run configuration by setting an environment variable like so:

[image: setting environment variables for a run configuration]